# Storing stripe and Facebook secrets in Key vault na scaling in Asp net core web application

Tags: facebook, asp.net-core, stripe-payments

I want to store (Stripe and Facebook) App Id and Secrets in azure key vault.
Then I want to call those secrets in my asp net core web application in appsetting.json

Can someone guide me pls?

I could not find any useful video or link.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this official Microsoft [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-8.0) that explains how to store and read secrets in Azure Key Vault.